# I cant generate the proper code to select the a specific filter on a BI dashboard I am working on

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I cant generate the proper code to select the specific filter on a BI dashboard I am working on.

I am trying to click on the pencil icon on the filter pane on a BI dashboard however my code combination does not work. Please, any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<div class="ew-e-gx ew-i-mat f-act running" data-bi-click="XXXXXXAction($event, level, $index)" data-bi-show="!item.disabled &amp;&amp; !item.locked" data-ng-class="{running: opened.edit == 'l'+$index}" data-translate="" data-translate-attr-title="we.actions.editfilter" title="Edit Filter"></di>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `xpath` the bellow :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//*[@title='Edit Filter' and contains(@class,'ew-e-gx ew-i-mat f-act running')])[1]"))).click();
```

Comment: Hi @Frian, Thank this code worked but, the issue I have 12 other filters with the same Element. The only thing that change is the class and it shows running when I clicked on each one. Please, can you elaborate more?

Comment: I've updated locator in answer, please try again,  that with the related `class`,  and i'm add count `[1]`, if available more than one, you can change `[1]` to `[2]` etc, you can highlight in inspect element.

Comment: Hi Thanks again, This time when I tried the updated code, it returned this error message:Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //div[@title='Edit Filter' and contains(@data-translate-attr-title, 'editfilter')] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info:

Answer (score 0):

The element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div[title='Edit Filter'][data-translate-attr-title$='editfilter']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@title='Edit Filter' and contains(@data-translate-attr-title, 'editfilter')]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB, Thank this codes did work but, however, this worked:             new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@title='Edit Filter']"))).click();
 but the issue I have now is I have, 12 other filters with the same Elements. The only thing that change is the class and it shows running when I clicked on each one. Please, can you look into it a little more? Thank you.

Comment: @PeaceT Can you raise a new question with all the details of your new requirement please?